# paired subject design test of proportions

Tags: t-test, proportion, wilcoxon-signed-rank, model-evaluation

I am analyzing a performance data set and would like to compare across two different conditions.

I have three subjects, which were tested over a number of trials.  Each trial had a chance of being in either condition, and had an outcome of either success or failure.

Here's the data in table form:

```
        Cond 1  Cond 2   Trls 1  Trls 2
Bat 1   0.054   0.170    n=37    n=88
Bat 2   0       0.090    n=37    n=88
Bat 3   0.026   0.137    n=38    n=87
```

I am wondering what kind of test to do that can compare the proportions but keep the paired subject design intact?

I am aware of the wilcoxon signed-rank but it just seems very weak in this case (perhaps I'm not setting it up correctly?).   A paired t-test is what I would like to use, but as these are proportions, and not close to prob=0.5, they aren't normally distributed.  I've also looked at McNemar's test, but each subject had multiple trials, so I'm also not sure it's appropriate.

Is there some other non-parametric test I could use?  Or a permutation test?  Or should I really be using wilcoxon?